# Kendo Categorical chart to display only points with non numeric x-axis

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using kendo UI dataviz charts to display data that has text(symbols) on x-axis and a numerical value on the y-axis. I have serverside datasource that provides the data. How can I achieve this?

I tried to use Scatter charts but they are XY charts and need numerical values on both x and y axis. I can display the data as a linecharts which are categorical but the line connecting the markers is meaningless in my case and I don't need that displayed.

here's an example of my data
var data = [{id:"1", number:"1.23", label:"A"},{id:"2", number:"4.11", label:"B"}]

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple line chart and set

1. markers visible
2. `series.opacity` to `0`

   ```
   series: [{
       field: "value",
       type: "line",
       opacity: 0,
       markers: {
           size: 5,
           visible: true,
       }
   }]
   ```

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-series.opacity